# rdlc skip hidden rows on condition

Tags: rdlc

I know this may sound trivial but I just can't find an answer to it.
I have a rdlc report in which I like to alternate row background color and for this I've used the following formula:

```
    =iif(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2, "#e5e5e5", "White")
```

I also need to hide some rows and for this I use the following formula:

```
    = Fields!MeanAeb.Value <> ""
```

where MeanAeb is a field in my report. My problem is that rowNumber also counts the hidden rows, so my table may have two consecutive rows with the same background. is there a way to take only visible rows into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if anyone has the same problem, I have an answer;

in the Code section of your ReportProperties add the following

```
    Dim customRowNumber as Integer = 0
    Dim previousRowNumber as integer = 0

    Function CustomRowCounter(conditionToTest as Boolean, rowNumbner as Integer) as Integer
        if(conditionToTest and rowNumbner <> previousRowNumber)
           customRowNumber = customRowNumber + 1
           previousRowNumber = rowNumbner 
        end if
        return customRowNumber
    End Function
```

then on the background field in your column properties add this condition:

```
    =iif(Code.CustomRowCounter(Fields!MeanAeb.Value="",RowNumber(nothing)) Mod 2, "#e5e5e5", "White")
```

this is nice because you can add any condition you like in place of Fields!MeanAeb.Value="". Just remember to use the inverse of the condition in your rowVisibility field, otherwise you may cause strange effects.

Oh and if you want a chess board look to your report just drop the previousRowNumber :)